# Can coronavirus contaminate public water systems?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

It's been reported recently that people are panic-buying stuff as the coronavirus epidemic worsens. I've even noticed that the local grocery store is low on hand sanitizer, paper towels, and bottled water.

I did some reading and traced links back to the DHS's ready.gov website, and it recommended preparing a 2-week supply of food, water, medicine, and hygiene products for ISOLATION, though I expect if you're sick you're supposed to plan a trip to the hospital. Most of that makes sense to me. The exception is the supply of water. We have public water systems that send drinkable water to us, so why do we need to prepare a stash?

I tried finding an answer online, but I couldn't. The only guess I have is that coronavirus can contaminate the public water system, and it's not guaranteed water treatment will work. Who here has the know-how on waterborne viruses and water treatment to address this speculation?

Comment: What if one person at the water plant gets sick, and the place is closed down and the other workers quarantined until decontamination is carried out? NB: I know noting about water plants, but no, the water system won't get "infected".

Comment: SE Biology is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, and questions are generally answered by people with biological rather than medical or epidemiological expertise. Although I understand your concern about the coronavirus outbreak, your question is not about the biology of the disease and is clearly off-topic here. I advise you to consult more appropriate reputable sources of information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: do you know how I can close this as off-topic? I can't delete it because the site says it has an answer

Comment: Try [medicalsciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Viruses can survive a few days in water, i.e. SARS can survive 22 days in lab grade reagent water and 7 days in pasteurized sewage. That is the time the virus takes to be at 99% of it's original concentration. (*from "survival of surrogate coronavirus in water"*).

Viruses can also spread via swimming pools, i.e. hepatitus A and norovirus have been associated with swimming pools. (*from "a review of waterborne viral deseases associated with swimming pools"*).

Boiling water will kill viruses. Children have very little reaction to the virus when they carry it, so it's likely that they act as a transmitter more than water does. I'm not worried about it at all by the way, just do what the doctors advise.

Comment: I f you deleted your answer the OP would be able to delete his question which he now recognizes is off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps transfer it to the medicalsciences.stackexchange.com

Comment: @com.prehensible
"Children have very little reaction to the virus when they carry it" - that's of interest to me as I wonder if it has been the basis of vaccine and treatment therapies research for other parts of the population. Please share further information if you have it. Thank you !

Comment: search for "juveniles immune coronavirus" "covid child immunity" you'll find some info although it is a complete mystery, nobody knows even what the T-cells for the new virus are and it's unkown why the effects are so variable.